# How the global scope function determine variables not alive anymore?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have wrote a function which binds a behavior to an element. Let's say we have two inputs. Then we want to be able to show hints on these input so,

```
function ElementHinter(element){
  element.showNotice = function( message, type) {
    var errorBorderStyle = "1px solid #cc3e22";
    var warningBorderStyle = "1px solid #cc9322";

    var parent = element.parents('.value');
    element.css("border", type == element.ERROR ? errorBorderStyle : warningBorderStyle);
    if (!parent.find('.error-message').length) {
      messagePublisher(message, type);
    }   
  }

  element.removeNotice = function() {
    element.css("border-color", "#aaa #c8c8c8 #c8c8c8 #aaa");
    element.parents('.value').find('.error-message').remove();
  }


  var messagePublisher = function(message, type) {
    var parent = element.parents('.value');
    var errorStyle = "#cc3e22";
    var warningStyle = "#cc9322";

    var html = "<span class='error-message'>" + message + "</span>";
    parent.css("color", type == ElementHinter.ERROR ? errorStyle : warningStyle);
    jQuery(parent).append(html);
  }
  return element;
}

ElementHinter.ERROR = "ERROR"
ElementHinter.WARNING = "WARNING"

var priceElement    = ElementHinter($('input#price'));
var discountPercent = ElementHinter($('input#discount'));

priceElement.showNotice("Bad price friend",ElementHinter.WARNING);
discountPercent.showNotice("Bad discount friend",ElementHinter.WARNING);
```

Now, if I get rid of the `var` in the `messagePublisher` both notices will be shown on **just one** element. Why that happens? if I get rid of the `var` what does `element` mean in that context?

Comment: do you understand what global variable is?

Comment: Check [Variable scope in Javascript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/advanced/variable-scope-javascript).

Comment: @dfsq yes I do, the question is when the function is global how `element` is interpreted.

Comment: In JavaScript 'var' will define new variable with visibility of current function. It is very new variable each time you call the function.

When you declare variable without 'var' keyword, it becomes part of 'window' object (which is global root object). So when you call same function again, the variable already exists.

TL;DR: always use 'var'. If in some case you think you don't need it, use 'window.your_var' expression, so you explicitly saying so.

Comment: I have edited the question title. This is is not explained in the question marked as exact duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Without `var`, the variable becomes **global**.  Thus, without `var`, there's only one `messagePublisher` variable and it's shared by all instances. It's as if you had the declaration:

```
var messagePublisher;
```

*outside* your function.

If you get in the habit of starting your script files or functions with the statement:

```
"use strict";
```

(exactly like that), then you'll get an error if you leave off `var` (or `let` or `const` in newer JavaScript).

Comment: Thanks. So, this is kind of bad practice right? Do you think the idea is generally good? To bind behaviors on elements like this?

Comment: @shampoo well, in this case you're not really binding to the *element*, you're binding to a jQuery object. Another approach would be to create those functions as your own extensions to jQuery, which would let you write `$("input#price").showNotice();`